# Installation of Sentifuge 2.1

Tags: permissions

I have downloaded sentrifugo.zip from http://sourceforge.net/projects/sentrifugo/files/

2) Then changed the permission to by below command
chown -R nobody:nobody Sentrifugo

3) nobody group was not there but i have added it. We have nogroup group available So i changed it to nobody:nogroup but it didnt worked to again changed it as mentioned point 2.

4) Still showing error on file and folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given 777 permission to Sentrifugo folder and that resolved this.